# Hi looking for help whit my HTML and CSS making it responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive

I'm looking help to make my HTML responsive whit all screen sizes. I have tried @media but it doesn't seem to work, maybe I include wrong elements?

Thank you!

I have 1 more question should I use wrapper around my elements instead of the border?

I want to make a gap between class=main and class=navigation.
Like I have done between the header and main( done it whit margin attribute)
but for some reason, I can't make it work whit margin-left value...

Any suggestions?

Thank you!

```css
 {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0px;
}

.head header {
 border: 1px solid;
 width : 100%;
 background-color: #4ca730;
 line-height: 150px;
 text-align: center;
}

.head h1 {
 display : inLine;
 color: #ecee1b;
 margin-top: 100px;
 margin-left: 1%;

}

.head img {
 padding-left: 10px;   
 background-image:url("Images/spaghetti.jpg");
 display: inLine;
 float : left;
}

.navigation {
 height: 400px;
 border-right: 1px solid;
 float: left;
 background-color: #4ca730;
}
nav a {
 display: block;
 padding-top: 20px;
 padding-left: 10px;
}
.form {
margin-top: 5%;
margin-left: 5%;
margin-right: 5%;
border-bottom: 1px solid;
border-top: 1px solid;
border-left: 1px solid;
background-color: gray;
}
.main {
 column-gap: 2em;
 height: 380px;
 margin-left: 5%;
 margin-top:1%;
 margin-bottom: 1%;
 border: 1px solid;
}
.main img {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 5%;
}
.main p {
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: 3%;
}

footer {
 border: 1px solid;
 background-color: #4ca730;
}

p {
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  nav, article {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="tuscany.css"/>
  
  <title>Tuscany Restaurant</title>
</head>

<body>
<div class="head">
 <header>
    <a href="Home.html">
 <img src="Images/spaghetti.jpg" width="200" height="150">
 </a>
   <h1>Tuscany Restaurant</h1>
   </header>
   </div>
   
<div class="navigation">
  <nav>
   <a href="Home.html">Home</a>
   <a href="Menu.html">Menu</a>
   <a href="Contact.html">Contact Us</a>
  </nav>
  <div class="form"
   <form action="/action_page.php">
  Username: <input type="text" name="usrname"><br>
  Password: <input type="text" name="pwd"><br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="remember" value="remember"> Remember me next time<br> 
  <input type="Submit" value="Log in">
</form>
</div>
</div>

<div class="main">
 <article>
  <img src="Images/restaurant.jpg" width="200" height="150">
 <p>Tuscany is Italian Restaurant. Tuscany Restaurant serves pasta,
pizza and beverages.</p>
</article>
</div>

<footer>
  <p>Last Update:20.02.2019<p>
   <p>Created By: Erki Kurvits<p>
</footer>

  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Include your @media example.

Comment: Your @media tag not closed..  ?

Comment: Also your `div` with the class `.form` is not closed :)

Comment: Thank you!
I have realised that I have alot misstakes whit not closing the tags and etc....

Answer (score 1):

Check your css. As others have mentioned there are couple of mistakes. In addition to this as a quick tip try to make the `H1` tag look nice when it's responsive. Currently "Tuscany Restaurant" comes as two lines when the browser is being resized.

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  nav, article {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
header a, header h1 {
    display: flex;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
}
```

Edited [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hLo20mv3/1/)

Comment: Thank you for the info!
and yes im trying to go over my css while doing it, but beginner still and hard to catch small mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help

*Please read about media query [Read here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)*

Your are miss to close div or media query tag.

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  nav, article {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;}
}
```

Comment: Thank you!

I also discovered that because nav and article are classes in my HTML, I dident include . (dot) in front of elements in my css

Comment: I did but it doesn't show.

Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

Answer (score 0):

a quick solution for your issue:

1) missing '{}' curly brackets

2)The method I used for media query: @media and (max-width: 600 px)
Media query should be closed like this:

```
@media and (max-width: 600px) {
 nav, article {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
 }
}
```